# How to copy one CGContextRef to another?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

in `-drawRect:`, I created a secondary `CGContextRef` using `CGBitmapContextCreate()`.

When I'm done with this context, I need to copy it's contents over to the "original" context of -drawRect:. How can I do that?

Reason why I create an additional context: I hope to get CGContextClipToMask() to work in a view that has a transparent background. My idea is to do all the mask-drawing and clipping in another context that has the appropriate color (non-transparent, no alpha), and then somehow paste that result back to the original context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use memcpy function. Read on google for how to use it.

Comment: Do you have a working sample for that...? I tried to simply memcpy the data of my drawingContext to an other one any nothing happened...

Comment: @Georg no buddy, I don't have working sample for this.

Answer (score 0):

just use CGBitmapContextCreateImage, and the actual physical copy of the bits occur only if the underlying data in the bitmap graphics context is modified.